# amavisd-release cannot release message from quarantine

Tags: amavis

I have amavisd-release version 2.002 when trying to release email from spam quarantine i have to type secred_id but i have no sql amavisd quarantine - only local

```
amavisd-release spam-id.gz 450 4.5.0 Failure: Secret_id is equired, but missing at (eval 92) line 286, <GEN104> line 5.
```

Im using quarantine ID and have no secret_id.

in script amavisd-release i have code

```
$socketname = '127.0.0.1:9998';
```

and in amavisd configuration have

```
$interface_policy{'9998'} = 'AM.PDP';
$policy_bank{'AM.PDP'} = { protocol=>'AM.PDP' };
$inet_socket_port = [10024,9998];
```

maybe i have to change smth to work when i have no sql quarantine method?

pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've manage to work it done :) Just find good info about configuration and change configuration of amavisd to:

```
$inet_socket_port = [10024,9998];
$interface_policy{'9998'} = 'AM.PDP-INET';
$policy_bank{'AM.PDP-INET'} = {
  protocol => 'AM.PDP',  # select Amavis policy delegation protocol
  inet_acl => [qw( 127.0.0.1 [::1] )],  # restrict access to these IP addresses
 auth_required_release => 0,  # don't require secret_id for amavisd-release
};
```

to work without secret_id i dont have (i think only sql method has this secret_id) its required to set

```
auth_required_release => 0,
```

just let me know if im wrong about secret_id

i was using this howto
http://gogs.info/books/debian-mail/chunked/antispam.amavis.html